# How to display 2 different text in a single label one after other?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How to display two different text in one label using timer simultaneously. For example, I want to display first Domestic after 10sec it should change to International in a single label.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use setTimeout() to display second text after 10 sec.

Comment: window.setTimeout(function(){
  $("#labelId").text('International');
}, 10000);

Comment: to change text in a loop you can use       window.setTimeout(function(){$("#labelId").text('International'); changeToDomestic();}, 10000);

function changeToDomestic (){
 window.setTimeout(function(){$("#labelId").text('Domestic'); changeToInternational();}, 10000);
}

function changeToInternational (){
  window.setTimeout(function(){$("#labelId").text('International'); changeToDomestic();}, 10000);
}

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<label id="myLabel">Domestic</label>
```

JS:

```
var changeLabel = function(){
  document.getElementById('myLabel').innerHTML = 'International';
}
window.setTimeout(changeLabel, 10000);
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/dyJBj/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var changeLabel = function(){

  var text = document.getElementById('myLabel').innerHTML;
  if(text == 'Domestic')
      document.getElementById('myLabel').innerHTML = 'International';
  else
      document.getElementById('myLabel').innerHTML = 'Domestic';

  window.setTimeout(changeLabel, 10000);
}
```

You can use this in body html tag: `<body OnLoad="changeLabel()">`

Comment: if i want to redirect domestic to international again...wht is d procedure?
like a loop...

Comment: thnx alot it ws very helpful